# Core plot: grid lines background color

Tags: ios, colors, background, grid, core-plot

I want to be able to put background color in the spaces between the grid lines of the y axis. Can this be achieved with core plot ? If so, how ?

Any help and/or example code will be much appreciated.

Thank you,

Petar

Comment: Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416254/core-plot-axis-alternatingbandfills-with-custom-axis-labels

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `alternatingBandFills` property to set the fill between successive major ticks. Here's an example with two different colors:

```
axis.alternatingBandFills = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CPTColor redColor],
                                                      [CPTColor greenColor], nil];
```

The array can contain any combinination of `CPTFill`, `CPTColor`, `CPTGradient`, and/or `CPTImage` objects. Blank (transparent) bands can be created by using `[NSNull null]` in place of some of the `CPTFill` objects. You can use as many different fills as you want; the axis will cycle through all of them and then repeat the pattern until all of the spaces are filled.

Axes also support what Core Plot calls "limit bands". This is a way to fill a section within a specific plot range. These don't automatically repeat like the band fills do.

The Axis Demo in the Plot Gallery example app shows both features.

Comment: Thank you once again Eric. That helped me a lot. I was very frustrated that there is no proper core plot documentation out there, but luckily there is stackoverflow and the helpful people.

Comment: You're right that there is no comprehensive "How to Use Core Plot" document, but it does include complete API documentation. It is available online at http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/index.html and is included in the release packages in both HTML and Xcode docset formats. The Documentation folder also contains several other useful documents.

Comment: I don't think that the API documentation is enough for a beginner to understand everything.